# How to launch python script as a windows Services

Tags: python, service, py2exe

Using Python 2.7 and Windows 7. I have a Python `file(.py)`. I want to launch this script as a Windows service, i.e. this code will keep on running from start to end and never terminate.

I can convert a `.py` file into an `exe-file` using **py2exe**. 
How to launch this and how the code flow works in services. Is it starts from line one to continue to last line, and then again starts from line one of code.

Comment: You might get better results by posting this on Superuser

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to start script from Windows startup. 
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7